# How to explicit set NULL value in a column in hibernate using setter method?

Tags: java, hibernate, apache-poi

I am reading an Excel file to populate a database table using Hibernate + Apache POI XSSF. For inserting the data, I am using the **SETTER** methods of the hibernate properties along with    `session.save()` instead of using the traditional **INSERT** approach.

The problem is that I want to explicitly set **NULL** values into nullable columns using setter methods when the corresponding Excel cell content is empty.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: this should not be community wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't `entity.setFoo(null);` work?

Comment: No it is not working. I am keeping the Excel cell as blank for setting null values and I am explicitly calling the setter method passing **null** as argument. But in the database it is getting inserted as empty string "" instead of null.

Comment: run in debug mode and verify this. It is not logical

Comment: I got it working finally. The trick was to avoid calling the setter method itself in order to insert null value for that column instead of passing java Null as argument to the setter method. Thanks a lot, Bozho.